# having trouble with jQuery if statement logo. Not responding how I expected

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

The basic premise of my site is six large boxes that shrink down into a graphical menu bar when you click any of them. An extra icon is added for the home button.

In order to position the boxes correctly in the first grid layout, I included a few extra classes such as `margin-zero`, `bottom-left` and `bottom-right`. I need to remove these classes when the images are shrunk down, and bring them back when they're expanded to full size.

So, I created a little `if` statement.

```
var counter = 0;

if(counter = 0) {
    jQuery(".two").toggleClass( "two-menu" );
    jQuery(".four").toggleClass( "four-menu" );
    jQuery(".images").toggleClass( "images-menu" );
    jQuery(".home").toggleClass( "home-menu" );

    jQuery(".four").removeClass( "bottom-left" );
    jQuery(".four").removeClass( "bottom-right" );
    jQuery(".two").removeClass( "margin-zero" );

    var counter = 1;
} else {
    jQuery(".two").toggleClass( "two-menu" );
    jQuery(".four").toggleClass( "four-menu" );
    jQuery(".images").toggleClass( "images-menu" );
    jQuery(".home").toggleClass( "home-menu" );

    jQuery(".four").addClass( "bottom-left" );
    jQuery(".four").addClass( "bottom-right" );
    jQuery(".two").addClass( "margin-zero" );

    var counter = 0;
}
```

To me it looks like this should work. However, in my JSFiddle prototype, it doesn't. Here is the link, so you can see all of the code and how certain boxes just off the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/NkYhh/

Comment: Well, for one, you are assigning instead of comparing in your `if(counter = 0) {`, it should be a `==` instead. Though that doesn't seem to fix it very much.

Comment: @Loyalar And it creates a new var with the same name, so the original is never changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you meant this?

```
var toggle =0;

function toggleIt() { 
  toggle=!toggle;
  $(".two").toggleClass("two-menu",toggle);
  $(".four").toggleClass( "four-menu",toggle);
  $(".images").toggleClass( "images-menu",toggle);
  $(".home").toggleClass( "home-menu",toggle);

  $(".four").toggleClass( "bottom-left",!toggle );
  $(".four").toggleClass( "bottom-right",!toggle );
  $(".two").toggleClass( "margin-zero",!toggle );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
if(counter == 0) {
```

Edit: also you are declaring counter 3 times.

Comment: How do you change a variable without resetting it?

Comment: Simply assigning it: `counter = 1;` You don't need to re-declare it.